# How to pass id of Parent Table to Child using OracleTransaction through OracleCommand

Tags: c#, transactions, plsql, odp.net

I recently ported some of my codes to use OracleTransaction of ODP.NET

I have the Following PL/SQL Codes:

for Parent table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertneworder (
   orderdate        IN   orders.order_date%TYPE,
   orderdescription IN   orders.order_description%TYPE
)
   RETURN orders.order_id%TYPE
IS
  orderid   orders.order_id%TYPE;

BEGIN
   INSERT INTO orders
               (order_date, order_description
               )
        VALUES (orderdate,orderdescription
               )
     RETURNING order_id
          INTO orderid;

   RETURN orderid;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
      NULL;
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
      RAISE;
END insertneworder;
```

Parent Table Trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bi_orders_pk
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON orders
   REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSTIMESTAMP, 'yyyymmddhh24missff3')
     INTO :NEW.order_id
     FROM DUAL;
END;
```

for Child Table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insertneworderdetails (
   orderid     IN   order_details.order_id%TYPE,
   quantity    IN   order_details.quantity%TYPE,
   productid   IN   order_details.prod_id%TYPE,
   itemcost    IN   order_details.itemcost%TYPE
)
IS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO order_details
               (order_id, quantity, prod_id, itemcost
               )
        VALUES (orderid, quantity, productid, itemcost
               );
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
      NULL;
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
      RAISE;
END insertneworderdetails;
```

Child Table Trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bi_order_details_pk
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON order_details
   REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSTIMESTAMP, 'yyyymmddhh24missff3')
     INTO :NEW.item_id
     FROM DUAL;
END;
```

Assuming that I created an OracleCommand for insertneworder and insertneworderdetails
I will pass it to this code...

```
public static bool ExecuteTransaction(List<OracleCommand> command) 
            {
                OracleConnection conn;
                conn = OraConnection.Instance.OracleConnection;
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) {
                    conn.Open();
                    }
                OracleTransaction trans;
                trans = conn.BeginTransaction();

                try 
                    {
                    foreach (OracleCommand cmd in command) 
                        {
                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    trans.Commit(); 
                    }

                catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    trans.Rollback();
                    return false;
                    }
            return true;
            }
```

MY QUESTION IS **"How can I pass the id of PARENT table returned by insertneworder function to insertneworderdetails through OracleCommand"?**

ANY HELP IS MUCH APPRECIATED...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'd need to add some code in the 'foreach' loop in your ExecuteTransaction function to detect when the 'insertneworder' function has been called, capture its return value, then detect when the 'insertneworderdetails' function is about to be called and bind the previously-captured return value to the appropriate parameter marker in the 'insertneworderdetails' call.  Sorry I can't be more specific, but I think that's a general way forward.

Share and enjoy.